# How to get range of values of a vector based on a range of values another vector?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a vector with statistical numerical values (Time).
I have a second vector also with numerical statistical values. (Distance)

I have calculated the quartile(using quantile function) of the second vector (Distance) and created a new  third vector with values 1 to 4,  so I can see to which quartile my vector (Distance) data belongs to.

How can I  get the range of values of the first vector (Time) based in a query of range  values of the third vector (Quartile)?

[image]

To be more clear:

```
**Time   -    Distance     -  Quartile(distance vector)

181     -     3.90         -    4

168      -    2.89       -    3

138     -     1.31       -    2

135      -    1.30      -     2

179    -      1.69      -     3

123    -      0.1       -     1

105    -      0.94       -    2 

95      -     0      -        1

775    -      3.41    -       3
```

How can I get Time ranges based on quartiles vector ranges, for example from 2-3,3-4 or 2-4?

From range 2 to 3 ,which range of Time values are needed?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Could you specify data structures? Perhaps showing output of `dput(data)`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Imagine that you have 3 columns, one is for Time values, one is for Distance values and the 3rd one is a quartile values related to the Distance, so I know to which quartile belongs each value of the Distance column. Now I want to know for each quartile which range of time value is needed, so I have to query for example; --> show me Time  Ranges for Quartile range 2 to 3.   The point is to get a range of time of a range of values (quartile).

Comment: I am unsure how repeating the values makes your question more clear. Does the second table do anything different from the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(Time = c(181,168,138,135,179,123,105,95),
                 Distance = c(3.9, 2.89, 1.31, 1.3, 1.69, 0.1, 0.94,0),
                 Quartile = c(4,3,2,2,3,1,2,1))

# select a range values for Quartile:
q.range = 2:3

# find range of Time column for this range of quartile:
range(df$Time[df$Quartile %in% q.range])
# [1] 105 179

# test it for another range of quartiles:
q.range = 2:4
range(df$Time[df$Quartile %in% q.range])
# [1] 105 181
```